# Different behavior of onclick="submit();" in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here is my problem:

base.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <head>
    <body>
        <form action="select.html">
            <select name="decide" onclick="submit();">
                <option>Choose Me!</option>
                <option>No me!</option>
                <option>We both know you want to choose me</option>
                <option>Nobody ever chooses me :(</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `onlick="submit();"` attribute has different behavior in different browsers.

In Opera and Chromium the site behaves as i want.
If you click on the select list, the list pops up and you can choose an entry.
In Firefox and Internet Explorer the onclick attribute fires the first item in the list as request to the server and then pops up the list when clicking on the select list.

[image]

How do i prevent Firefox and Internet Explorer from firing first and asking later? :/

I'm not very familiar with Javascript and jquery and i'm using Django 1.8.4
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `onchange` or `onselect`

Comment: Do what @Tushar said if you must do it inline

Comment: @Tushar But if OP click on already selected item, onchange event won't be fired. He should set a default value then

Comment: @A.Wolff There is no need of that. Is that mention in question(_I don't see_)

Comment: onchange also has the problem if the user chooses same entry again it also wont be fired

Comment: You say it works on chrome but i suspect it doesn't work exactly as you expect it. And anyway, user could select option without clicking any but using keyboard

Comment: @Tushar the first option (selected by default then) is: `<option>Choose Me!</option>` looks clear enough for me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you actually want to fire when an item is selected not when the dropdown is clicked, so change onclick to onchange

Edit - something like this perhaps (pure js not jquery)

```
<form action="select.html" name="frmDecide">
<select name="decide" onchange="submitForm(this);">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option>Choose Me!</option>
    <option>No me!</option>
    <option>We both know you want to choose me</option>
    <option>Nobody ever chooses me :(</option>
</select>
```

and then the js

```
function submitForm(sel)
{
    if (sel.value != "")
    {
        frmDecide.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried onchange. And it works almost properly. Except if you want to choose the selected item again, or want to select the first entry in the list that is marked. And i need the functionality of onclick as it behaves in Opera and Chromium in my project. :/

Comment: @BigZ easiest way would be to set a default value asking user to choose one in list `<option>Please select</option>`

Comment: It looks like this might work as i need. Thx alot :)

Comment: Is it possible to add some functionality if the user clicks the same entry again that the request gets fired again?
Because if you select an option in my project the view calls a parser for  the selected option and returns the parsed data to the site, using the same view and same select list again with the selected option as initial value.

Comment: If the form is posting back, the dropdown should default back to the "Please select..." option anyway, so each subsequent select will be a new one. If the form is staying put (some kind of ajax call or something), then you could try setting the selectedIndex of the dropdown afterwards...

Inside the js function...

        sel.selectedIndex = 0;

Answer (score 0):

If you want a placeholder (kind of), you could use that instead:

```html
    <select name="decide" onchange="submit();">
        <option selected style="display: none;">Select your option</option>
        <option>Choose Me!</option>
        <option>No me!</option>
        <option>We both know you want to choose me</option>
        <option>Nobody ever chooses me :(</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thx, this is also worth a try in my project. :)

Comment: down votes should be allowed only after comment to make sure its a valid down vote lol

Comment: What? I assume you mean me :(

Comment: @AdamJeffers Sure i, but don't worry, i don't really much care :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

**HTML**

```
<select id="my-select" name="decide">
    <option>Choose Me!</option>
    <option>No me!</option>
    <option>We both know you want to choose me</option>
    <option>Nobody ever chooses me :(</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#my-select').on('click', function(){
     // do something
     submit();
});
```

or

```
$('#my-select').on('change', function(){
     // do something
    submit();
});
```

or

```
$('#my-select').on('select', function(){
     // do something
    submit();
});
```

Comment: im guessing because its `select`, you should `use on change`. `on click is for button`

Comment: This is exact same behaviour as OP's code so won't fix issue for sure

Comment: I quote "And i need the functionality of onclick as it behaves in Opera and Chromium in my project. :/" from there, the rest can be managed in a number of ways.